# Why does React resolve undefined/boolean/null to string only when they are variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to wrap my head around JSX.
I've found a very weird behavior.
This is my code:

```
const name = undefined;
const myFunc = () => undefined;
let template = (
  <div>
    {myFunc()}
    {name}
    {undefined}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(template, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

The output is **one time**:
undefined

Why is the const "name" the only undefined value that is resolved to a string?
What is the difference between this const and the other two expressions?
(Same with Boolean and null.)
Please see my code here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/navehazan/pen/YJvZom)

Comment: Technically nothing should be displayed since all falsy values should be ignored. It seems one of the values gets stringified somehow.

Comment: Cant reproduce in JsFiddle, what React version do you use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `JSX` is syntactic sugar for [`React.createElement(component, props, ...children)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored)
It will ignore these types (see [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored)):

- Boolean
- undefined
- null

I just realized that this happens only on some editors like codepen because they run the code in the global context and [window.name will always be a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name#Notes).

> window.name will convert all values to their string representations by
>   using the toString method.

If you change the variable to something else, lets say `name1` it behaves as expected.

```
const name1 = undefined;
const myFunc = function(){return undefined};
let template = (
  <div>
    {name1}
    {undefined}
    {myFunc()}
  </div>
);
```

By the way, stack-snippets behave the same:

```js
console.log('name is ', name);
const name = undefined;
console.log('and now name is ', name);
const name1 = undefined;
const myFunc = function(){return undefined};
let template = (
  <div>
    {name}
    {name1}
    {undefined}
    {myFunc()}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(template, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Other Editors like `codesandbox` or `jsfiddle` will wrap the code in a function, hence there is no conflict with the `window.name`.

Answer (score 1):

The output here would be empty between your divs. I put this code into [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc40pnju/) to demonstrate:

```
const name = undefined;
const myFunc = () => undefined;
let template = (
  <div>
    {myFunc()}
    {name}
    {undefined}
    Hello world
  </div>
);
```

Notice all you can see is the "Hello world" that I added.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the global variable `name` is the property [window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) and will always be a string.

> `window.name` will convert all values to their string representations by using the toString method.

```js
name = undefined
foo = undefined
console.log('`name` is a', typeof name, ', but `foo` is a', typeof foo)
```

Use a different global variable name, and it should work as expected. But you should typically not use global constants in your templates anyway.